# Is Youtube API right for us?

Tags: youtube-api

I've looked over the Youtube API guidelines and wanted to ask if we qualify for commercial use. We're a travel start-up that wants to enable users to upload videos of themselves on our website about the trips they want to take and to potentially get funding for their trip (Kickstarter for travelers). Below I've added a portion from the guideline, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Farhad Rizvi

Commercial Use.

You agree not to use the YouTube API for any of the following commercial uses unless You obtain YouTube's prior written approval:

the sale of the YouTube API, API Data, YouTube audiovisual content or related services, or access to any of the foregoing;
the sale of advertising, sponsorships, or promotions placed on or within the YouTube audiovisual content or player; or
the sale of advertising, sponsorships, or promotions on any page of the API Client containing YouTube audiovisual content, unless other content not obtained from YouTube appears on the same page and is of sufficient value to be the basis for such sales.
The following commercial uses are permitted provided that You comply with all other terms and conditions of this Agreement:

the sale of an API Client;
uploading an original video to YouTube, or maintaining an original channel on YouTube, to promote Your own business or artistic enterprise;
using the YouTube API to show YouTube content on an ad-enabled API Client (such as an ad-enabled blog or website), subject to the advertising restrictions set forth above in Section 2;
the placement of Your own branding on the API Client, provided that it does not interfere with YouTube audiovisual content playback or with any YouTube branding; or
the sale or distribution of any device that contains or runs an API Client; or

Comment: I don't think this is very programming-related, perhaps if you needed help with the API itself, I could help.

Comment: Actually that depends - what are you planning on selling? If you are planning on selling access to YouTube videos, that is against the ToS. If you are planning on selling an app that curates YouTube videos, that is probably not a violation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. For users to upload on your site you can use [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/) project.
And when you reach to a scale, you can definitely apply for a [YouTube partner program](https://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/creator-benefits.html).